# Какие три лучше способы есть чтобы уменьшить код в react?

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть вот такой код

```
function App() {
  const [listImg, setLis] = useState([]);
  const [Indx, setIndx] = useState(0);
  const [resErrX, setErrorX] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const Res = await fetch(......);
        const Product = await Res.json();
        setLis(
          Product.x
            .map((value, index) => ({
              key: `${value}`,
              z:`${index}`,
              y: `${value}`,
              onClick: () => {
                setIndx(index);
              }
            }))
        );
      } catch (error) {
          setErrorX(error.message);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (...);
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы вот эта часть кода.
App.js

```
({ key: `${value}`,
   z:`${index}`,
   y: `${value}`,
   onClick: () => {
   setIndx(index);
              })
```

было написано в файле DD.js;

```
const DDX = {
              key: `${value}`,
              z:`${index}`,
              y: `${value}`,
              onClick: () => {
                setIndx(index);
              };
```

потом чтобы импортировать в файл App.js .
но я получаю Error setIndx(index) что не существует,

можете показать три способа написание кода Чтобы это часть кода было написано в файле DDX.js потом чтобы использовать в App.js.
если вы знаете другие способы уменьшить код можете показать ваши варианты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете написать Вот так

DD.js

```
export default const DDX = `{
              key: `${value}`,
              z:`${index}`,
              y: `${value}`,
              onClick: () => {
                setIndx(index);
              }`;
```

App.js

```
import DDX from './DD.js';

setLis(Product.x.map((value, index) => (eval.DDX)));
```